# Wait until media element has naturalDuration information

Tags: vb.net, mediaelement

I need to make a loop to look at a lot of mp3 files and getting their naturalDuration property using a mediaElement. The problem is that mediaElement need some time to load every single file and .source property works like async process (I think) because I have to click two times on below code if I want to obtain naturalDuration property. First click I have just 00:00:00 value, second clik give me real value.

```
Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click

    mediaElement.Source = New Uri("\\Mac\Home\Desktop\NOVEDADES01\AbrahamMateo-OldSchool.mp3")
    textBlock.Text = mediaElement.NaturalDuration.ToString

End Sub
```

If I try to wait after .Source instruction, the application keeps on loop.

```
Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click

    mediaElement.Source = New Uri("\\Mac\Home\Desktop\NOVEDADES01\AbrahamMateo-OldSchool.mp3")
    Do
    Loop Until mediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds > 0
    textBlock.Text = mediaElement.NaturalDuration.ToString

End Sub
```

I also have try set .source through an async process and wait for mediaOpenend event, but it look like mediaElemento can not end until the first click was ending

How could I get real value of naturalDuration inside one single process or function just after set .source property and without playing the file?
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, late and may be not so elegant but this was my solution for getting duration of a mp3 file. I used MusicProperties Class.

Public Function infoMP3(elfichero As String) As String

```
    Dim salida As String = ""
    Dim miTask = Task.Run(Async Function() As Task(Of String)
                              Dim musicFile As StorageFile = Await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(elfichero)
                              Dim FileProperties As StorageItemContentProperties = musicFile.Properties
                              Dim musicFileProperties As MusicProperties = Await FileProperties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync()
                              Dim tiempo = musicFileProperties.Duration
                              Dim horas As String
                              If tiempo.Hours < 10 Then
                                  horas = "0" & tiempo.Hours.ToString
                              Else
                                  horas = tiempo.Hours.ToString
                              End If
                              Dim minutos As String
                              If tiempo.Minutes < 10 Then
                                  minutos = "0" & tiempo.Minutes.ToString
                              Else
                                  minutos = tiempo.Minutes.ToString
                              End If
                              Dim segundos As String
                              If tiempo.Seconds < 10 Then
                                  segundos = "0" & tiempo.Seconds.ToString
                              Else
                                  segundos = tiempo.Seconds.ToString
                              End If
                              Dim autor = musicFileProperties.Artist
                              Dim titulo = musicFileProperties.Title

                              Dim presalida As String = "[" & horas & ":" & minutos & ":" & segundos & "];[" & titulo & "];[" & autor & "]    " & elfichero
                              Return presalida
                          End Function)
    miTask.Wait()
    salida = miTask.Result
    Return salida

End Function
```

To get access to the files later on Windows 10, you have to save permission for the files and/or folders. Do this when you select them.

...
Dim listToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(rutaS)
...

where rutaS is an SotorageFolder object.